# I need to integrate Gravity Forms with Car Query API

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Hey I'm trying to get gravity forms to load dynamic content from the Car Query API. For the API to work, all I need is to put in a custom name and a custom ID and then the javascript will handle the rest. I can't seem to get Gravity Forms to allow me to create custom names and custom ID's for my forms without them being overwritten. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you checked this out: https://stevegrunwell.com/blog/custom-field-ids-gravity-forms/

Comment: I have checked that, but I cannot get the custom ID to render on the front end. I'm going through Gravity docs right now, but I've never used the plugin before so I'm experiencing some confusion!